# Javascript scroll down to a section

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am working on my portfolio website. I want to add a css class when user scroll to a specified section.( I want to use a Javascript event)

For example, first hide an element with css, then when the user scrolls down to that section, show that element with vanilla Javascript.

```
<div id="info"> info... </div> 
#info { display :none;}
```

loading Javascript code ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a big issue, you could use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) but it is not supported on all browsers, another way is to use the scroll event on the window.

```
function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
    let timeout
    return function() {
      let context = this,
        args = arguments
      let later = function() {
        timeout = null
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
      }
      let callNow = immediate && !timeout
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
    }
  }

  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img')

  function checkSlide(e) {
    images.forEach(img => {
      const slideInAt = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight - img.height / 2
      const imageBottom = img.offsetTop + img.height
      const isHalfShown = slideInAt > img.offsetTop
      const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom
      if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
        img.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        img.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(checkSlide))
```

This is code I made following [Wes Bos](https://courses.wesbos.com)' javascript30 course, which I highly recommend and it is free

Summary:

The funciton debounce is to stop from calling the event too many times, more than needed.

The const images are all the images on my dom, I'm checking the images but you can check for whatever div you want to check.

checkSlide function checks that I've reached and not passed each image, here you can check for each div that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could track the scroll position of the window and the top position of the target element. Then, when the element reaches some point (for instance half the window height), it can be given a class that modifies some css properties like the `opacity` or `display`.

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  let doc = document.documentElement;
  let top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);

  let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  for (i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i) {
    let target = targets[i];
    if(target.offsetTop < (top + (windowHeight/2))) {
      target.classList.add("visible");
    }
    else {
      target.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  }
});
```

Take a look at this [demo](https://jsbin.com/ninewix/4/edit?html,css,js,output).